# Why AWS CloudWatch Log Group and Stream Name cannot be changed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I was trying to change AWS CloudWatch Log Group and Stream Name as follow:

```
cat <<EOT >> /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf
[/var/log/messages]
file = /var/log/messages
log_group_name = MY_LOG
region = ap-southeast-1
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
EOT
```

And I've tried to stop and start CloudWatch agent, log group name and stream name could not be changed as expected. Please help me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf` and not `/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf`.

The rest of your configuration file looks fine.

You can also check your `/var/log/awslogs.log` for eventual error messages linked to IAM permissions.

See also [Why can’t I push log data to CloudWatch Logs with the awslogs agent?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/push-log-data-cloudwatch-awslogs/).

Comment: Additionally - rebooting your EC2 instance will catch updates to the `awslogs.conf` file. I `stop` & `start`ed a few times but the rename of my log stream was only picked-up after reboot.